# HttpResponse data not available to jquery code

Tags: jquery, django, ajax, python-3.x, bootstrap-4

I am trying to implement a success or error pormpt on submission of a contact_me form.

I am writing this for a portfolio website and the data fields of contact_me form is been emailed to the client and the email service in the back-end is working properly. I am using class based django-views.

```py
    @method_decorator(csrf_protect)
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        subject = request.POST.get('subject')
        name = request.POST.get('name')
        email = request.POST.get('email')
        message = request.POST.get('message')

        try:
            mail_message = Mail(
                from_email=email,
                to_emails='mailid@website.com',
                subject=subject,
                html_content="from: " + name + " Message: " + message
            )
            response_data = "SUCCESS!!"
            print(response_data)
            return HttpResponse(json.dumps({'data': response_data}),content_type="application/json")
        except Exception as e:
            print(str(e))
            return HttpResponse(json.dumps({"nothing to see": "this isn't happening"}),content_type="application/json")

        return render(request, self.template_name)
```

```
function create_contact() {
    $.ajax({
        url:'',
        type:"POST",
        data: {
          name : $("input#name").val(),
          email : $("input#email").val(),
          phone : $("input#subject").val(),
          message : $("textarea#message").val(),
        },

        success: function(json) {
          console.log("SUCCESSFUL!!");
        },

        error: function(xhr,errmsg,err) {
          console.log(errmsg);
          console.log(err);
          console.log("error!!");
        } 
      });
};
$("#contactForm").on("submit",function(event) {
      console.log("contactForm onclick worked");
      create_contact();    
    });
```

the above code outputs a

> error
>
> error!!

output of console.log(errmsg) is

> error

output of console.log(err) is

> 

*blank*

in browser console even on successfull submission of the contact_me form

Status of the response on back-end is

> SUCCESS!!

Comment: print the `errmsg` and `err` on your browser console and update your question with that.

Comment: what is the status code of the response? you have printed 2 statements (1 for try and 1 for catch) in your code, what is the output in your terminal?